# Linear Programming 3 decision variables (past exam paper question)

Tags: linear-programming

[image: A picture of an exam question]

This is an exam question I was practising. I have the general understanding of Linear programming, but how would you go about finding the Decision Variables,  Objective function and Constraints for this?

My Opinions:
Decision variables:

$M_1$- # of  Model 1 to be produced

$M_2$ and $M_3$ (similar definition to $M_1$)

Objective function:
I'd Multiple the Cost to make in house by cost to buy from subcontractor

to get Minimise: $3900M_1+7500M_2+27300M_3$

Constraints:

$3M_1+1.5M_2+2M_3 \geq 0$

$1.25M_1+2.5M_2+0.75M_3 \geq 0$

$M_1,M_2,M_3 \geq 0$

No idea where number order would go? Do I use it in the Constraints and multiply by the Hours?

Now, am I on the right track?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! For self-study questions, please try & explain how you're already thinking about the problem - how would *you* go about finding the decision variables, objective function and constraints - giving your reasoning; & expect to get hints rather than a complete answer back.

Comment: By the way, this may be a better fit to another SE site - I'm having a look now. In any case, please edit your question as per my previous comment (as other sites have the same policy on self-study questions) & we'll migrate it to another site if necessary. Update: It'll be either the Mathematics or Computational Science site.

Comment: I did what you asked.

Comment: Try math stack exchange, this is an operation research question.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still dithering over whether it'd be better on Mathematics or Computational Science - won't be long.